# How do references in Perl work

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain the `push` statement in the following Perl code to me? I know how push in perl works but I can't understand what the first argument in following push command represents. I am trying to interpret someone's script. I tried to `print "@a\n";` but it only printed `ARRAY(0x9aa370)` which makes me think that the push is not doing anything. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
my @a = (); 
my $b = 10;
my $c = 'a';
push(@{$a[$b]}, $c);
```

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreftut

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's break it down.

The `@{...}` is understood from ["Using References" in perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)

> Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type.

So what is inside `{ ... }` block had better work out to an *array reference*. You have `$a[$b]` there, an element of `@a` at index `$b`, so that element must be an arrayref.

Then `@{...}` dereferences it and `push`es a new element `$c` to it. Altogether, `$c` is copied into a (sole) element of an anonymous array whose reference is at index `$b` of the array `@a`.

And a crucial part: as there is in fact no arrayref <sup>†</sup> there, the [*autovivification*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) kicks in and it is created. Since there are no elements at indices preceding `$b` they are created as well, with value `undef`.

Now *please* work through

- tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and
- data-structures cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

while using `perlref` linked in the beginning for a full reference.

---

With complex data structures it is useful to be able to see them, and there are  tools for that. A most often used one is the core [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), and here is an example with [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm)

```
perl -MData::Dump=dd -wE'@ary = (1); push @{$ary[3]}, "ah"; dd \@ary'
```

with output

```
[1, undef, undef, ["ah"]]
```

where `[]` inside indicate an arrayref, with its sole element being the string `ah`.

---

<sup>†</sup> More precisely, an `undef` scalar is dereferenced and since this happens in an *lvalue* context the autovivification goes.  Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for a comment. See for instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401306/4653379) with its links.

Comment: Re "*as there is in fact no arrayref there*", More precicely, because it's undefined.  Because of autovivification, `push @{ $ref }, LIST;` is effectively short for `push @{ $ref //= [] }, LIST;`

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you, added, as a footnote for now (may rewrite text)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the following two assertions:

- `@a` starts out as an empty array with no elements.
- `$b` is assigned the value of 10.

Now look at this construct:

`@{$a[$b]}`

To understand we can start in the middle: `$a[$b]` indexes element 10 of the array `@a`.

Now we can work outward from there: `@{...}` treats its contents as a reference to an array.  So `@{$a[$b]}` treats the content of element 10 of the array `@a` as a reference to an anonymous array.  That is to say, the scalar value contained in `$a[10]` is an array reference.

Now layer in the push:

`push @{$a[$b]}, $c;`

Into the anonymous array referenced in element 10 of `@a` you are pushing the value of `$c`, which is the character "a".  You could access that element like this:

`my $value = $a[10]->[0]; # character 'a'`

Or shorthand,

`my $value = $a[10][0];`

If you pushed another value into `@{$a[10]}` then you would access it at:

`my $other_value = $a[10][1];`

But what about `$a[0]` through `$a[9]`?  You're only pushing a value into `$a[$b]`, which is `$a[10]`.  Perl automatically extends the array to accommodate that 11th element (`$a[10]`), but leaves the value in `$a[0]` through `$a[9]` as `undef`.  You mentioned that you tried this:

`print "@a\n";`

Interpolating an array into a string causes its elements to be printed with a space between each one.  So you didn't see this:

`ARRAY(0xa6f328)`

You saw this:

`ARRAY(0xa6f328)`

...because there were ten spaces before the 11th element which contains an array reference.

If you were running your script with `use warnings` at the top, you would have seen this instead:

```
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at scripts/mytest.pl line 12.
          ARRAY(0xa6f328)
```

...or something quite similar.

Your structure currently looks like this:

`@a = (undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,['a'])`

If you ever want to really get a look at what a data structure looks like, rather than using a simple print, do something like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@a;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a discussion over this yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841066/pass-array-by-value-to-hash-value-in-perl)

what it means is that
`@a` is an array

```
$a[$b]
```

is a cell in the array
the `@{}` syntax helps perl understand that the cell in question is an array so you can preform push/pop operations on it.
if you do

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@a;
```

you should see something like:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          [
            'a'
          ]
        ];
```

as you can see, the 11th cell is an array containing the letter 'a' as its only value
the push operation on an empty cell could have also been written as:

```
$a[$b] = [$c]
```

Comment: i would appreciate if down-voters would specify why they down-voted, i would like to improve the quality of my answers